# transact to VRFD20.rollDice pending

Tags: solidity, remix

Guys whichever function i'm calling after deployment , its saying transact to be pending... what is the reason behind this , i'm not getting it
[image]

Comment: Hi! In general, questions need to provide more information than this for people to be able to answer. What is the contract being deployed? (If it's a single short contract, paste it into the question using three backtics (```) to create a code block. If it's a suite, paste the parts you think are relevant, and link to the repo.) Where is the contract being deployed? How is the contract being deployed? Providing this information should make it easier for someone to answer. Cheers!